# jQuery individual lists sliding up and down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not really experienced with jQuery but I couldn't find an answer for this. What I exactly want to do is when people click on the img with the class machine-dropdown that the div overview does slideToggle. I got multiple lists on this page with the same construction so I need them to work individual.

```
<img class="machine-dropdown" src="/theme/cliptech-xl/img/arrow-machine-drop.png" />
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="category-divider"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="overview">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <a href="machines">
                    <img class="actueel-img" src="" />
                </a>
                <a href="">
                    <span class="machine-overzicht-title"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tryed it with many methods that jquery already has. .closest .first .find but still when i click it slides all lists.

Thanks for the help already!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

Change your HTML to this:

```
<img class="machine-dropdown" data-target="#overview-1" src="/theme/cliptech-xl/img/arrow-machine-drop.png" />
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="category-divider"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="overview" id="overview-1">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <a href="machines">
                    <img class="actueel-img" src="" />
                </a>
                <a href="">
                    <span class="machine-overzicht-title"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Note that I've added `data-target="#overview-1"` to the `machine-dropdown` image and `id="overview-1"` to the `overview` div.

Now use the following javascript/jquery:

```
$(function(){
    $(".machine-dropdown").each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            var target = $(this).data("target");
            $(target).slideToggle();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello Thanks for your great solution. I only had to make a counter in php to make this work :)! Works like a charm! Thankssss!

Answer (score 0):

use `this` attribute in your code.

```
$('.machine-dropdown').click(function(){
$(this).next().next().next().find('.overview').slideToggle();
});
```

I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: Hi this did not work because the class .machine-dropdown does not contain all the div's with the information.

Comment: i have updated the code.if you have same structure all over the lists it will work perfectly.